# Input field must not be empty

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input field where the field can't let you search unless you type/select something. How would I go about doing this?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control pg-csr-customer-search CSRinputBut" aria-label="" id="CustomerSearchText" name="CustomerSearchText" value="" placeholder="Search Customer" required>
```

[image]

I need to show this warning when the user just clicks or hits enter.

```
displayCustomerSearchMessage('<i class=\"fa fa-exclamation-circle pull-left\"></i> Sorry, missing selected Customer Id. Please make a selection from the results listing.', 'warning');
```

Comment: Show us your 'search' event handler ... I think you will need to do `event.preventDefault` and display the message in case the input is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="CustomerSearchText" id="CustomerSearchText" onblur="checkTextField(this);" />


//modify following code as your need
function checkTextField(field) {
    if (field.value == '') {
        alert("empty!!!");
    }
}
```

**update**

```
<form onsubmit="return checkTextField(this)">


function checkTextField(form) {
  var text = form.CustomerSearchText.value;

    if (text == '') {
            return false
        }


  return true;
}
```

Comment: This lets me click and type but when I click outside I get the alert. I don't want the user to be able to just hit enter and get a result, I need to show a message saying something like: field can't be empty or something along those lines.

Comment: you could use the logic at form submit and stop form from being posted